# Is it possible for MSSQL 2012 & 2008

Tags: sql-server

My main question, is that is it possible to have an instance of MSSQL 2012 and 2008 on the same machine?

The reason for this question, is that I need to restore some databases (currently in version 539) and re-export them, so they are in a acceptible format for my main MSSQL 2012 instance?

Would this cause complications anywhere on the line? or would it be alright for this to take place?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend migrating from one version to another. Depending on your code, multiple problems will arise.

Comment: At a previous job, I had 2000, 2005, and 2008 r2 all on one machine without problems, altough some people had issues when initially installing multiple versions.  It should work, based on a history of it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple versions of SQL on your machine, it will just need separate instance names.

Comment: I'd be very careful when installing SQL 2008 after SQL 2012 is already installed, especially if the 2012 is already a production instance. If you do go down that path, make sure you have solid backups of your server (and not just your databases) before you start. (If it were me, I'd find another machine/VM/something, and install 2008 there.) If you are installing SQL2008 first, then SQL2012, then forget I mentioned it.